# how to make rounded corner as radio button in React

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, components, rounded-corners

i would like to make these two rounded corner as a radio button where if i pressed on one the other will be turned off in React.

Comment: please give an example ,it  is quite easier to understand

Comment: @AvneeshKumarSinghal i did look at the image of what i want press on it and you can see it

Comment: mean which button you select you should be select in react js

Comment: @AvneeshKumarSinghal i want to make a rounded corner element like in the image and if you can see one of them has a blue corner and the other is not, meaning i want them to be radio button when i press on the first one the second is turned off

Comment: can you please put some code so, can understand better .